# clear the output of old external command in VIM

Tags: vim

When use *! {cmd}*  in vim, the output of previous command is not cleared by default. For example, I executed two external command in VIM: *! make* and *! gcc*. When I type *! gcc*, the output of previous command *! make* is included:

```
user@desktop:~$ vim 

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

shell returned 2

Press ENTER or type command to continue
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

shell returned 4

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I want vim to clear these old outputs so that I can view the output of current command clearly,  could you offer any advice for this?

Answer (score 4):

You could run `/usr/bin/clear` first .e.g.

```
:!clear && make
```

Alternatively you could open a new scratch buffer, using [this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1599).

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap vim's execution of all command inside an arbitrary script by setting the shell variable in `.vimrc` to the path of a script that you can create as you please. Line to add to `.vimrc`:

```
set shell=~/.vim/shell-wrapper.sh
```

Then within the named script you can call `clear` before running the command originally requested. Minimal contents of `~/.vim/shell-wrapper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
shift # strip the -c that vim adds to bash from arguments to this script
eval $@
```

You can find my full config here: https://github.com/timabell/dotmatrix (may change over time; last commit at time of writing was https://github.com/timabell/dotmatrix/commit/1098fcbcbcefa67b7a59d7a946cda1730db8ad8b )